# Can we have a marker for questions that have been answered (solved) on the question list page?

Tags: feature-request

As on the question page, there is a tick mark to show accepted answer. So could we have any such marker on the question list page for question with accepted answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer count is filled with a color in case of an accepted answer. In the other case the answer count is in white color.

[image]